# Como fazer RegEx para um formato "serial" de numeros?

Tags: java, regex

Como fazer o RegExp do seguinte formato:

```
2015.1.123.5432
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Danilo notei que deletou a sua outra pergunta, acho que poderia ter esperado, eu até mesmo abri uma questão no meta acaso queira participar http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4221/3635 - Acaso queira participar do chat também seja bem vindo: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que seja algo como:

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

ou então:

```
\d{4}\.\d{1}\.\d{3}\.\d{4}
```

- O `\d` representa qualquer valor numérico de 0-9
- O `{...}` representa a quantidade de caracteres representado pelo que está antes de `{`
- O `+` significa que ele vai procurar o caractere antes do sinal mais `+` até encontra o próximo (que no caso é o `.`).

Vamos suporte que em `2015.1.123.5432`

- 2015 sempre será 4 digitos
- 1 será de 1 á 2 digitos
- 123 será de 3 á 4 digitos
- 5432 será de 4 digitos a "ilimitados"

Então você deve fazer a regex assim:

```
\d{4}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{3,4}\.\d{4,}
```

- `{1,2}` quer dizer que vai procurar números como 1, 2, 13, 99. Mas vai ignorar 100 ou maiores
- `{3,4}` quer dizer que vai procurar números como 123, 200, 998, 9900. Mas vai ignorar números menores que 100 e maiores que 9999.
- `{4,}` só vai aceitar números de 1000 pra cima.

Se o numero serial tiver espaços você pode usar `replaceAll` para remove-los antes de usar a RegEx ou depois (se for usar a regex pra extrair os dados de um texto), assim:

```
String minhaSrt = " 2015 .1 .123 .5432 ";
minhaStr = minhaStr.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

Ou usar o `\s` que vai remover espaços e tabs:

```
String minhaSrt = " 2015 .1 .123 .5432 ";
minhaStr = minhaStr.replaceAll("\s", "");
```

Comment: Sabe se tem como ignorar o espaço em branco caso a string esteja com espaço?

Comment: 2014.1.444.1254   ;   Nome Da Pessoa